# How to allow user to try again or quit console program in C#?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, exit

I have created a game that gives a player 5 chances to play after which I would like to ask the player if they would like to play again or quit. I have seen it done in Python, but I do not know python. My code works perfectly fine, but I would like to add these two additional functions
How can I achieve these functionality in C#? 
For reference this is what my code main class code looks like.

```
namespace NumBaseBall
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*      Let's Have Some Fun          *");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*           Welcome To The          *");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*       Number Baseball Game        *");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t*************************************\n");

            GameResults gameresults = new GameResults();

            for (int trysCounter = 1; trysCounter <= 5; trysCounter++)
            {
                gameresults.Strikes = 0; 

                Random r = new Random();
                var myRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);
                var computerNumbers = myRange.OrderBy(i => r.Next()).Take(3).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("The Game's Three Random Integers Are: (Hidden from user)");
                 foreach (int integer in computerNumbers)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("{0}", integer);
                 }

                 List<int> playerNumbers = new List<int>();
                 Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Three Unique Single Digit Integers and Press ENTER after each:");
                 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                 {
                      Console.Write("");
                      int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                  playerNumbers.Add(number);
                 }

                 gameresults.StrikesOrBalls(computerNumbers,playerNumbers);
                 Console.WriteLine("---> Computer's Numbers = {0}{1}{2}", computerNumbers[0], computerNumbers[1], computerNumbers[2]);
                 Console.WriteLine("---> Player's Numbers = {0}{1}{2}", playerNumbers[0], playerNumbers[1], playerNumbers[2]);
                 Console.WriteLine("---> Game Results = {0} STRIKES & {1} BALLS\n", gameresults.Strikes, gameresults.Balls);
                 Console.WriteLine("You have played this games {0} times\n", trysCounter);

                  gameresults.TotalStrikes = gameresults.TotalStrikes + gameresults.Strikes;

                  Console.WriteLine("STRIKES = {0} ", gameresults.TotalStrikes);

                   if (gameresults.TotalStrikes >= 3)
                   {
                       gameresults.Wins++;
                       Console.WriteLine("YOU ARE A WINNER!!!");
                       break;
                   }
               }
                       if (gameresults.TotalStrikes <3)
                       Console.WriteLine("YOU LOSE :( PLEASE TRY AGAIN!");
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain how your code is not working so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Please take time to format your code as well, so it's not all over to the right - and ideally reduce it to a *minimal* example. It's not at at all clear what the "arrays" and "list" tags have to do with the problem, either.

Comment: Hint to solving this: separate the concerns. Move most of the code out of your main method into a method called `PlayGame` or whatever. At that point, we don't need to care what's in there - we only need to fix asking whether or not the user wants to play again, and calling the method again if they do.

Comment: One possible way would be to put the for loop in a separate method, in which you initialize the variables. When the user loses, call that method again to reset the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your code inside an loop which checks if the user wants to continue:

```
while(true) // Continue the game untill the user does want to anymore...
{

    // Your original code or routine.

    while(true) // Continue asking until a correct answer is given.
    {
        Console.Write("Do you want to play again [Y/N]?");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (answer == "Y")
             break; // Exit the inner while-loop and continue in the outer while loop.
        if (answer == "N")
             return; // Exit the Main-method.
    }
}
```

But perhaps it would be better to split one big routine up into seperate routines.

Lets rename your Main-method to `PlayTheGame`.

Split up my routines into:

```
static public bool PlayAgain()
{
    while(true) // Continue asking until a correct answer is given.
    {
        Console.Write("Do you want to play again [Y/N]?");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (answer == "Y")
             return true;
        if (answer == "N")
             return false;
    }
}
```

And now the Main-method can be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
         PlayTheGame();
    }
    while(PlayAgain());
}
```

You'de have to move some local variables to the class as static fields. Or you could make an instance of a Game class, but I think that is one step to far right now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could accomplish this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int exitCode =1;
System.Environment.Exit(exitCode);
```

Environment.Exit is the preferred way to exit your program since the Kill command "*causes an abnormal process termination and should be used only when necessary."*[msdn]

Comment: A normal exit from function Main would be even better, since `Exit` does not execute all outer finally-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First, take the suggestion of moving the code for the actual game playing into a separate function. It will clean things up a lot.

Something like

```
private static bool PlayGame()
{
    // Win branch returns true.
    // Loss branch returns false.
}
```

This then lets you greatly simplify the `Main` function allowing it to only handle the menu functionality.

For the actual menu functionality, I tend to prefer `do/while` loops. You have a bit of an extra stipulation that you only ask after 5 plays, but that's easy enough to deal with.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int playCount = 0;
    string answer = "Y";
    bool winner;

    do
    {
        if(playCount < 5)
        {
            playCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Play again? (Y/N): ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while(answer != "Y" && answer != "N");
        }

        winner = PlayGame();
    } while(!winner && answer == "Y");

    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
}
```

You could simplify it a bit by moving the test for 5 games into the `if` conditional with the use of an increment operator. The only issue is if someone plays your game a billion or so times, things might get weird.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int playCount = 0;
    string answer = "Y";
    bool winner;

    do
    {


        if(playCount++ > 3)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Play again? (Y/N): ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while(answer != "Y" && answer != "N");
        }

        winner = PlayGame();
    } while(!winner && answer == "Y");

    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
}
```

Edit: Changed things a bit as it looks like in your original code the game ends after the person wins the game.

---

Per your question in your comment below, you could make a static instance of your `GameResults` class in your `Program` class. Your code would end up looking something like the following

```
class Program
{
    private static GameResults results = new GameResults();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Code
    }

    private static bool PlayGame()
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

In `PlayGame` you would just use the static `results` object instead of creating a new one every time `PlayGame` is called.

Comment: @BradfordDillion When you say " move the code for the actual game playing into a separate function. It will clean things up a lot." what code are you exactly referring to? Because I have a external class called `GameResults` that also handles some of the functionality of the game

Comment: @AaronLWG probably most of the code that exists in your `for`loop above could be moved into a separate function.

Comment: @BradfordDillion Can I as you for some additional help? I am trying to increment and SAVE the number of wins the player makes if he continues to keep playing. However everytime he tries again his previous winning count gets whipped clean and he starts back at zero again. I know its because I am making a new instance of `GameResults` on every new game played, but I am not sure how to save his winning count. Can you please assist?

Comment: @AaronLWG See edit above in answer to your question.